# Show checkout sidebar within form Div

Tags: magento2, checkout, checkout-summary

I want to move the checkout sidebar with in left side of the FORM div in my custom theme.

the sidebar of checkout, where the summary of the products is rendered through KO Template.

I actually want to move both form and sidebar summary in main container of

```
<div class="row">
```

is there any way which i can do the accomplish this?

http://prntscr.com/n6bqnn

Comment: can you add any images or the code that you want to achieve or you are trying respectively

Comment: you want to move cart page summery ?

Comment: @Hassan yes, i have attached the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code to

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary</item>
                                                <!--<item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">summary</item>-->
                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/summary</item>
                                                </item>
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/totals</item>
                                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">totals</item>
                                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/summary/totals</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!-- sort order for this totals is configured on admin panel-->
                                                            <!-- Stores->Configuration->SALES->Sales->General->Checkout Totals Sort Order -->
                                                            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/subtotal</item>
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Cart Subtotal</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="shipping" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/shipping</item>
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping</item>
                                                                    <item name="notCalculatedMessage" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Not yet calculated</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/grand-total</item>
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Total</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                    <item name="itemsBefore" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!-- merge your components here -->
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                    <item name="cart_items" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/cart-items</item>
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="details" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details</item>
                                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="thumbnail" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/thumbnail</item>
                                                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before_details</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/subtotal</item>
                                                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">after_details</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>

                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                    <item name="itemsAfter" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!-- merge your components here -->
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
```

You have to override **`checkout_index_index`** file & if you just compare both files just removed entries which appear on side bar and add them to new desired position under shipping address:

[image]

Comment: can you please write a short description that what you actually did.

Comment: ok I explain you

Comment: great i got it now.

Comment: I added visual explanation

Comment: Also If you want to move on cart page look my answer on :


https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/231484/magento-2-move-cart-summery